# Importing null date from Excel

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have an excel sheet from where I am reading excel cel values and importing to DB

Using Apache POI :

```
 if (row.getCell(8) != null) {
          setActualDeparture(DateUtil.getJavaDate(row.getCell(8).getNumericCellValue()));
   }
```

The excel sheet has null on Cell 8 , so it should not import anything . but it takes dates like 1899-12-31T00:00:00

What could be the issue ?

Comment: Cell 8 is the 9th cell in the row. does that change anything?

Comment: Yeah that doesnt change anything ..

Comment: Please note : This excel sheet is created using a java script.

Comment: If cell(8) was null, you would get a NullPointerException by the getNumericCellValue() call. Obviously, it's not null. Open the excel spreadsheet. Do you see any data in there?

Comment: It is open and it is null (blank) ( white space)

Comment: The condition would be false if it was null and the code wouldn't run. I can't help you, sorry. There's something else going on.

Comment: I have 1 excel sheets, one which i manually create and one through a java script. The manual one has no problem  - it shows a blank value but this one gets the default dates

Comment: I have no experience with making excel sheets with javascript.

Comment: Are you sure that that cell really contains a date, and not a number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Row.getCell(int cellnum)` returns only NULL if there is nothing stored in the file for this cell. It returns the cell if there is something stored in the file for this cell. Even if this is only a NumberFormat for example or any other information for this cell.

But there is a second method `Row.getCell(int cellnum, Row.MissingCellPolicy policy)`  http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Row.html#getCell%28int,%20org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row.MissingCellPolicy%29 which can be used in your case.

Example:
[image]

There is nothing in A1 but there is a special NumberFormat and not General applied.

```
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.*;
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;

class GetEmtyCellTest {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  try {

   InputStream inp = new FileInputStream("workbook.xlsx");
   Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(inp);

   Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);

   Row row = sheet.getRow(0);

   System.out.println(row.getCell(0).getNumericCellValue()); //0.0
   System.out.println(row.getCell(0, Row.RETURN_BLANK_AS_NULL)); //null


   FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("workbook.xlsx");
   wb.write(fileOut);
   fileOut.flush();
   fileOut.close();

  } catch (InvalidFormatException ifex) {
  } catch (FileNotFoundException fnfex) {
  } catch (IOException ioex) {
  }
 }
}
```